# Django invitation application

Tags: django, invitation

I want to create a site where people would need an e-mail invitation to subscribe and where I would be the only one allowed to invite people.
I think the [invitation application](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-invitation/overview) is what I need. Is it correct ? Is it easy to implement ? Any hint is welcome.

For the installation of django-registration and django-invitation, I have read I could just put the unzipped files in my django path. Is it correct ? Or should I use easy install ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be able to put any app/modul in the django folder and it should work.

However, there are a few things that need not be overlooked.

1. Make sure you don't overlook to edit the settings.py and the urls.py as instructed for each specific app
2. Do check if there are any dependencies. Some apps may require certain libraries that need to be installed such as imaging etc.
3. Some apps have more complicated process and need additional settings, files, and adjustments.

Specifically for Django registration 2 lines in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sites',
'registration', # add this line!
```

)

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7 # And this line! #One-week activation window; you may, of course, use a different value.

as well as in urls.py:

```
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

as for the invitation, its almost the same:

https://bitbucket.org/david/django-invitation/wiki/Home#basic-use

Good luck